# Why is the animation duration of jquery's animate function inconsistent?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

Please have a look at these simple jquery animations:

```
animate.mouseenter(function () {
    animate.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, duration);
});

animate.mouseleave(function () {
    animate.stop().animate({ opacity: 100 }, duration * 10);
});
```

My questions:

- Why is the animation time of these two animations more or less equal, although `duration` is multiplied by 10 for the `mouseleave` animation?
- Is there a particular reason for this behavior?
- Is the factor exactly 10 or some other floating point value which is just close to 10?

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TCMjd/3/

I also added an example of the `fadeIn`and `fadeOut` functions, where equal `duration` parameters yield equal animation times as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an opacity of `1` is fully opaque. You're animating all the way to 100, so it hits 1 pretty quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/e8N4Q/

```
var animate = $(".animate"),
fade = $(".fade"),

duration = 500;

animate.mouseenter(function () {
    animate.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, duration);
});

animate.mouseleave(function () {
    animate.stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, duration * 10);
});

fade.mouseenter(function () {
    fade.stop().fadeOut(duration);
});

fade.mouseleave(function () {
    fade.fadeIn(duration * 10);
});
```

Comment: How embarrassing... Thanks! But then the animation should be 100 times slower instead of 10, shouldn't it?

Comment: It does the animation over the same amount of time, it just increases the opacity more per tick.

Comment: 500 ms is half a second; 5000 ms is 5 seconds; so 10 times is actually 10 times, funny how that works... :)

Comment: good catch @JasonP! sometimes another set of eyes really is all it takes.

Comment: No reason to feel terrible. Everyone needs a second pair of eyes sometimes.